# Finding intersection of two buckets using Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have data structured as the following in an elastic index:

```
[ { customer_id: 1, date_of_purchase: 01-01-2022 },
  { customer_id: 2, date_of_purchase: 01-02-2022 },
  { customer_id: 1, date_of_purchase: 01-02-2022 },
  ....
]
```

I want to find the numbers of users who have bought something in both September and October, but having issues figuring out how to make a query for this. Any suggestions would rock, thanks!

Comment: What is the type of the `date_of_purchase` field in the index mapping please?

Answer (score 0):

I have used following aggregations

[1. Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

[2. Bucket selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

[3. Date Range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html)

In query I have filtered all documents which either have purchase date in Jan or in Feb. This reduces number of documents for aggregation to work on. In aggregation I have done a group by(terms aggregation) on customer_id and then further grouped documents based on date ranges(1 bucket for each month). Then I have eliminated months(using bucket selector) which have zero documents i.e. with no purchase date in that month and further eliminated customers which have 1 or zero buckets

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date_of_purchase": {
              "gte": "2022-01-01",
              "lte": "2022-01-31"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date_of_purchase": {
              "gte": "2022-02-01",
              "lte": "2022-02-28"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cutomers": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "range": {
          "date_range": {
            "field": "date_of_purchase",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "to": "2022-01-31",
                "from": "2022-01-01"
              },
              {
                "to": "2022-02-28",
                "from": "2022-02-01"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filter_months": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "doc_count":"_count"
                },
                "script": "params.doc_count>=1"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "bucket_count":{
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "bucket_count":"range._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.bucket_count>1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "cutomers" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "range" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z-2022-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "from" : 1.6409952E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "to" : 1.6435872E12,
                "to_as_string" : "2022-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z-2022-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                "from" : 1.6436736E12,
                "from_as_string" : "2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "to" : 1.6460064E12,
                "to_as_string" : "2022-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```